# Modify game using external file

Tags: android, mobile, configuration, flash-develop, haxe

In Flash, for example, I can place an **xml** file along with the **binary**, then if I modify some variable the game will change for everyone.

How to achieve something like that in **Android**? I know that for every change I make to the game, the player would need to download a new update.

But the main goal I'm looking for, is modifying a game stats **without** the need for recompile the **entire** APK.

I'm working with **Haxe+OpenFL**.

Answer (score 1):

You can either store the settings in a database connected to your application or save them on the SD card.

The integrated databases are assigned to a certain application and only this application cann access them. So you can save them there even though only the application can change them.

The other way would be to use the SD card (or other external memory) and save them there. Access to the SD card is possible for each application so anyone could change the settings then.

To create or change the settings create a service in your application that queries this settings from an external server.

Comment: How does that work with the update system on Android? If I change something in the database, then update the app on the store, does the user get that update?

Comment: The database is local to the device. So you can change this from the app itself (without going over the shop). You simply have to inform your app about this (e.g. by asking a server at the start of the app).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a SQLite database, but it has to be on your SD card or on your device. Here is the reference for SQLite on Android:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#openDatabase

However you may be able to download the file to your SD card, check out this URL where someone downloaded an image to their SD card:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296850/how-do-i-transfer-an-image-from-its-url-to-the-sd-card

Answer (score 0):

I'm loading a local file from SD card (Android 4.3) like that:

```
// loading local file
#if android
loadTextFromURL( "/sdcard/PROjekty/testHaxe.txt" );
#end
#if flash
loadTextFromURL( "file:///C:/O/PROjekty/testHaxe.txt" );
#end
#if windows
loadTextFromURL( "C:/O/PROjekty/testHaxe.txt" );
#end
...

// loading file over http
loadTextFromURL( "http://oskarswierad.com/temp/testHaxe.txt" );
...

public function loadTextFromURL( address:String ):Void {
    var newLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    newLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
    newLoader.addEventListener( Event.COMPLETE , textLoaded );

    newLoader.load( new URLRequest( address ) );
}
...

public function textLoaded( evt:Event ):Void {
    var text:String = cast(evt.target, URLLoader).data;

    trace( text );

    evt.target.removeEventListener( Event.COMPLETE , textLoaded );
}
```

You'll need to find out how to get path to SD card dynamically. I mean on every device model or system version the path can be different.